# Using directores for each domain using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have a host and some domains. I want use a directory for each domain. Unfortunately my host dose't support vhosts. I made .htaccess file in root to redirect every domain request to it own directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain1\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain1/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain2t/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

It worked well and my site accessabe with "http://domain1.com" address. I try to use CodeIgniter as my sites framework.
So I configure base-url in CI config file to "http://domain1.com/domain1/" but it worked for main page only and when I request another controller like "http://doamin1.com/somecontroller", the page not found.
Also I setup .htaccess in site directory as follow.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /domain1

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

How can I do this job so that browser addressbar do't show directory like
"http://doamain1.com/domain1/somecotroller" (this form is working).

Tanks everybody.

**UPDATE**
My routes.php.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'main';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: mange your `routes.php`.

Comment: off-topic: redirecting robots.txt is a good recipe to break some stuff

Comment: @HikmatSijapati can you explain more, plz?

Comment: can you post your routes.php?

Comment: @HikmatSijapati I posted my routes.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I after some tests got the answer that I need.
I change root .htaccess like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain2/
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain2/$1 [L]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain1/
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain1/$1 [L]  
</IfModule>
```

And every .htaccess in domain directory to as follow

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /domain1

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Also change config.php file base-url to "http://domain1.com/"